# Convert pdf tabular data into excel using java

Tags: java, csv, pdf, pdfbox

I want to convert my pdf tabular file into CSV file.

This is the code what I have written but I  am getting only 5 columns name only not their value.

Code--

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> readParaFromPDF(String pdfPath, int pageNoStart, int pageNoEnd, int noOfColumnsInTable) {
    ArrayList<String[]> objArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfPath));
        document.getClass();
        if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
            PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            tStripper.setStartPage(pageNoStart);

            tStripper.setEndPage(pageNoEnd);
            String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
            // split by whitespace
            String Documentlines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
            for (String line : Documentlines) {
                String lineArr[] = line.split("\\s+");
                if (lineArr.length == noOfColumnsInTable) {
                    for (String linedata : lineArr) {
                        System.out.print(linedata + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    objArrayList.add(lineArr);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
    }
    return objArrayList;
}
```

Comment: Add more tags for better search

Comment: It would help considerably if you could post the value of `pdfFileInText` so we can see what you're working with. Does `pdfFileInText` actually have the data you are seeking?

Comment: Please share the pdf in question. The observation that you get only the headings, not the content, might indicate that the content is stored not as page content but probably as form field or other annotation content. In that case you'd have to extract the data differently.